# How to set expire on sub keys of Sorted Set in Redis using Node.js

Tags: node.js, redis

Here I created a Sorted Set using node.js
I want to delete elements of Sorted Set after some time.That means expire sub keys after some time.
code:

```
 var redis = require(redis);
 var client = redis.createClient();

 //Add elements into mySortedSet along with their score.

 client.zadd("mySortedSet","1","one");
 client.zadd("mySortedSet","2","two");
 clinet.zadd("mySortedSet","3","three");
```

I want to set expire on the sub keys.Expire "one" from "mySortedSet"

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Redis only has option of expiring full set after a certain time, not elements inside the set.
What you can do is run a scheduled task periodically to expire/delete/set score of invalid elements inside the set.

Comment: Very true although as an alternative/addition to the periodic expiration, you could also expire (via the deletion of timed-out elements with `ZREMBYSCORE`) whenever you read/write to that Sorted Set in your code.